# push notifications using Blazor Server

Tags: .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app on which users can subscribe to an asset and whenever the asset changes the UI is updated. That already works.

Now I would like to implement a feature that when change's severity is "Critical" not only the UI updates but the user also gets a push notification. Let's assume that a change is represented with such class:

```cs
public class MyChange
{
   public string Severity { get; set; }
}
```

Is this even possible with Blazor Server, if so then how? Or should I use Blazor WebAssembly?

Comment: Do you want to pop up a message or use the browser's [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API) that would raise an OS notification? If you only want to display a popup, you can use any Toast or Modal library to display the message. This works without requiring user permission

Comment: The Notification API works through a service worker so it requires some JavaScript code. The [Blazing Pizza workshop code](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/blob/master/docs/09-progressive-web-app.md#sending-push-notifications) uses JavaScript [to create subscriptions](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/blob/master/src/BlazingPizza.ComponentsLibrary/wwwroot/pushNotifications.js). The end user would have to allow the site to display notifications too

Comment: I meant the browser's Notification API that would raise an OS notification @PanagiotisKanavos . The blazing pizza project is Blazor Webassembly, does it matter?

Comment: It uses Javascript for the subscriptions though. If you want to use the Notification API, you'll have to use Javascript as well. [The notification tutorial](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/blob/master/docs/09-progressive-web-app.md#sending-push-notifications) uses Javascript scripts through interop

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which part is not working and what was implemented for the push. But to give you a full answer yes you can do this. With SignalR you can send Push messages to the clients. Actually Server hosted Blazor already using SignalR to update HTML but you [can use it for Balzor WASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server) as well.

Once you set up push messages and clients receives it then you can show Notifications. You can use this [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Notifications) also [docs](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/Notifications.md) and [demo](https://blazorextensions.z6.web.core.windows.net/notifications) available. To prompt one of the following notifications:

- Alerts: static "banner" (this has severity check `Type` property)
  [image: Alert demo]
- Toast messages: more dynamic "popup" like message inside your app (this has severity check `Type` property)
  [image: Toast demo]
- HTML5 Notification API: system notifications outside of your app (you cannot really "style" System notifications)